# spring boot: can't initialize a postgresql datasource

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following bean configured.

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.etlTarget")
public DataSource datasourceTest() {
    System.out.println("************");
    System.out.println("************");
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Then error log is:

```
************
************
2014-12-14 21:12:35.718  WARN 21758 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Collection org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.AbstractBatchConfiguration.dataSources; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasourceTest' defined in class path resource [com/testcom/etc/ETLJobRepository.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'datasourceTest' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

Key error message is

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No supported DataSource type found
```

The gradle setting is

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.0.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.3.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

I tried hard to figure it out why it error out, but don't find out the root cause

The property is

```
datasource.etlTarget.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/example
datasource.etlTarget.driverClassNname=org.postgresql.Driver
datasource.etlTarget.username=postgres
datasource.etlTarget.password=test
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You made a typo in your configuration:

```
datasource.etlTarget.driverClassNname=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Should be:

```
datasource.etlTarget.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

(i.e. `driverClassName` instead of `driverClassNname`)